# How to get current post category details inside "loop"?

Tags: php, functions, categories, loop

I have a rather simple problem I can't solve. I have custom styling for my cards and one of the elements of the cards is the category, when I access the_category() from the Loop it comes with its own weird styling (looks like a list item anchor). I would like to get the url of the category and the name of the category within my while loop, my code is shown below:

```
<div class="container body-margin">
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="row">
            <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()), 'thumbnail' ); ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $url ?>" class="img-responsive card-image" />
        </div>

        <div class="row card-body">
            <div><a class="card-body-category" href="#the-category-url"><?php the_category(); ?></a></div>
            <div><h4 class="card-body-title"><b><?php the_title(); ?></b></h4></div>
            <div><p class="card-body-date"><?php the_date(); ?></p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Most of the solutions I saw had people accessing their tags outside the while loop with the get_the_category() function, this does not suit what I want to do, would be really grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_the_category` works within the loop as well, don't pass a post ID and it will default to the current post in the loop.

[The first example in the docs for `get_the_category`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/#user-contributed-notes) show how to output the url and name of the first (or only) category:

```
$categories = get_the_category();
if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[0]->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a>';
}
```

EDIT: Your original code with the above example added:

```
<div class="container body-margin">
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="row">
            <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()), 'thumbnail' ); ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $url ?>" class="img-responsive card-image" />
        </div>

        <div class="row card-body">
            <?php

            $categories = get_the_category();
            if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
                echo '<div><a class="card-body-category" href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[0]->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a></div>';
            }

            ?>
            <div><h4 class="card-body-title"><b><?php the_title(); ?></b></h4></div>
            <div><p class="card-body-date"><?php the_date(); ?></p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: <?php $categories = get_the_category(); ?>
      <div><p class="banner-article-topic"><?php esc_html( $categories[0]->name ); ?></p></div> Tried this, tried with an anchor, tried to introduce local $count variable, tried to make $categories global (my content is in a separate file) and access the array elements using a $count variable, all of these solutions did not work.

Comment: the code in your comment doesn't work because you don't `echo` the value returned from `esc_html`. that function doesn't produce any output on its own.

Comment: Thanks for that, but you mentioned that the example shows "how to output the url and name of the first (or only) category" what about the current item of the loop? It doesn't seem to be given or maybe I missed it.

Comment: It shows the first (or only) category *for each post in the loop*. Calling `the_post()` populates a global variable, `$post`. Functions that can/have to be used in the loop use the contents of `$post` to get data for the current post.

Comment: $post = get_post();
  $category = get_the_category( $post->ID );
  $category_url = esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) );
  $category_name = esc_html( $category->name ); Not working, this is the only stuff I change.

Comment: does a solution to this problem?

Comment: You misunderstood my last comment, WordPress sets `$post` for you, you don't need to, and you don't need to supply a post ID. Did you try just copying and pasting the code I gave you? I edited your original code and added the example code from above. Tested, working.